# get grpbuttonitem index c++

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    ButtonGroup1->Items->Add() ;
    ButtonGroup1->Items->Items[i-1]->Caption = Q_Cat->FieldByName("cat_name")->AsString;
    ButtonGroup1->Items->Items[i-1]->OnClick = ButtonGroup1->OnClick;
```

as you can see here i created 10 groupbuttonitems dynamically using for loop here in item called "ButtonGroup1" and i created onClick event for each one = "ButtonGroup1" onClick Event
and here is ButtonGroup1 OnClick Event

```
void __fastcall TFrm_Test2::ButtonGroup1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Edit1->Text = ButtonGroup1->ItemIndex;
}
```

But the problem is when i click on any groupbuttonitem it always = -1 it cannot be unchanged

[image]

and when i tried to get item index using this code

```
Edit1->Text = ButtonGroup1->Items->Items[1]->ID;
```

i can't get which group button item was clicked

so anyone can help me ..

Comment: Is this code for C++ Builder?

Comment: Does `Add()` insert at the back or the front? If the front, you are always modifying the same instance.

Comment: the front, you right . But if i use insert(int) it will be the same problem

Comment: C++ Builder @VTT

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all i solved it finally using event called OnButtonClicked in buttongroup component events . like this

```
     void __fastcall TFrm_Orders::BG1ButtonClicked(TObject *Sender, int Index) {
Edit1->Text = ButtonGroup1->Items->Items[Index]->ID;
 }
```

[here is the event name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq7xJ.jpg)

Index value is the index of clicked item on buttongroup